# Firestore composite index for subfields

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an application using **Firestore** and I'm running into an issue with a query that involves subfields.

I'm adding a search feature that allows users to filter articles by various criteria, such as year, season, genre, and studio.

To implement this feature, I'm using a Firestore database and a query function that takes search terms and filters as input and returns a list of matching articles.

Specifically, I'm trying to query on the genres and studios subfields of my documents, but when I run the query, I get an error message that says,

> FirebaseError: The query requires an index.

I created a function to generate query, then use it in getData(q) function.

```
export function generateSearchQuery(
  searchTerms: string,
  filters: {
    year: number | "";
    season: string;
    genre: string;
    studio: string;
  }
): Query<DocumentData> {
  const docRef = collection(firestore, "example");
  let q = query(docRef);

  if (searchTerms) q = query(q, where("title", "==", searchTerms));
  if (filters.year) q = query(q, where("year", "==", filters.year));
  if (filters.season) q = query(q, where("season", "==", filters.season));
  if (filters.genre) q = query(q, where(`genres.${filters.genre}`, "==", true));
  if (filters.studio)
    q = query(q, where(`studios.${filters.studio}`, "==", true));

  q = query(q, orderBy("id", "desc"), limit(20)); //id is needed, for fetching more by using startAfter() function 

  return q;
}
```

I think it's not possible to create composite index with studio and genre as there are unlimited patterns, eg. genres.Action, genres.Comedy, etc.

example,

```
      "studios": {
        "Studio A": true,
        "Studio B": true,
        "Studio C": true
      },
      "genres": {
        "Action": true,
        "Comedy": true,
        "Drama": true,
        "Sci-Fi": true
      }
```

Can someone help me figure out how to create the composite index I need? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need to create one index for each possible combination.  A single index will never be able to handle them all, no matter how you choose to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I only found out this method,

Create some combine keywords

dummy example

```
const arr1 = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];
const arr2 = ["happy", "sad", "angry"];
```

generate some keywords, create a new item "keywords" to store this arr.

```
function combineArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  const combinedArr = [...arr1, ...arr2];

  for (const item1 of arr1) {
    for (const item2 of arr2) {
      combinedArr.push(`${item1}, ${item2}`);
    }
  }

  return combinedArr;
}
```

generate target

```
function combineValues(value1, value2) {
  let combinedValue = "";

  if (value1) {
    combinedValue += value1;
  }

  if (value1 && value2) {
    combinedValue += ", ";
  }

  if (value2) {
    combinedValue += value2;
  }

  return combinedValue;
}

const target = combineValues(filters.genre, filters.studio)
```

finally,

```
where("keywords", "array-contains", target)
```